# Field to local or global variable

Tags: java, android, global-variables, local-variables

I have a doubt about which option would be a better one in order to have a more understandable code. I have a variable that will be used just inside one method but, as this variable is a configuration variable, I think that it would be nice that this would be a global one. So I have created it on the top of the class as:
private final int VARIABLE = 5000;

But then, as this variable is used just once, the Android Studio launches a warning that says "Field can be converted to a local variable". Do you think that is better to keep this variable as a global one (in order to be more clear for the future) or it is better to set it as a local variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you are using it in only single method then it is better to put in local scope

Comment: Or it should be defined as a constant: private **static** final int VARIABLE = 5000;

Answer (score 0):

Keep all your variables which are not going to change, for example base url strings etc in a separate java file in a separate package like Utils. Place all your variable there and make them static so that you can directly access them by using the class name.

Comment: It's actually a good solution IMO. Don't understand the negative vote.

Comment: That's a terrible advice. Constants should be defined in the class where they belong. Not in a single class. Imagine the size of such a class and the names of the constants if the JDK stored all its constants in a single class. Imagine how awful it would be to find the right one.

Comment: There is no rule that states that constants that are to be used over the entire application need to be defined as class scope variables of your activities or fragments. I still feel that it will be more modular project structure to have a separate package like utils and have classes in them that would contain the constant values. My answer still stands.

Comment: JB Nizet, you could perfectly define a "CONSTANTS.java" file within which you could define different classes for constants attendings different needs. This is a perfect solution and I also follow this rule. What if you need to use a constant 40 times throughout your program? Why should we define it in a given class and not in a more-general, constant-specific class?

Comment: Because it simply doesn't scale, and is counter-intuitive. When I use the Cipher class, which has two modes of operation ENCRYPT and DECRYPT, it's much more natural to look for these constants in Cipher than in a global Utils. When I use BorderLayout, I expect to find the constants used (NORTH, EAST, etc.) in BorderLyout, and not in Utils. Same for all the other classes. If the JDK followed your advice, we would use a Utils class containing thousands of constants, with horrible names such as BORDER_LAYOUT_NORTH instead of NORTH to avoid clashes.

Comment: Hi, I have a constants file where I have defined the global static variables. But this variable in particular is just to define a locale configuration of a timer, so I think that I would be better if that variable is defined in the same class that will use it. But I doubt whether the variable must be locale (as it is used just once) or, in order to keep the code clear, be declared on top of the class. Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: @FVod defining it as a constant in the class is what you should do. But a constant is static. If it's not static, it's not a constant, and every instance of the class has one separate variable, consuming memory for nothing.

Comment: @JBNizet I just have one thing to say after reading your comment. If you cannot explain it simply then you yourself have not understood it simply.

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal Just because you can't understand something or admit you're wrong doesn't make me a bad explainer. My answers here allow me to gain 326K reputation points. So I guess some people can understand my answers.

Comment: I still believe that constant static field that might get used over the entire project should  be placed in a separate files under a package say utilities. This is the most modular approach and the project structure will look cleaner.

Comment: @JBNizet You might have 326K reputition points, but we do not answer just to gain reputition points sir, we answer so that the developer community helps out each other and being helpful is the biggest reputation that one gains